# Proof of Toeplitz's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $a_n$ be a real sequence convergent to $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $t_{k,n}$ (where $1\le k \le n$) be a sequence of weights such that:

$$(I) \quad \forall k \lim_{n \to \infty}t_{k,n} = 0$$
$$(II) \quad \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n t_{k,n} = 1$$
$$(III) \quad \exists M : \forall n\ \ \sum_{k=1}^n |t_{k,n}| \le M$$

Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}s_n =a$, where $$s_n \equiv \sum_{k=1}^n t_{k,n} \cdot a_k.$$

My proof:

Let $N_1$ be such that $n \ge N_1 \implies |a_n - a| < \varepsilon$. Consider 
$$|s_n -a| = \left| \sum_{k=1}^{n} t_{k,n} \cdot a_k -a \right| = \left| \sum_{k=1}^{N_1 -1} t_{k,n} \cdot a_k + \sum_{k=N_1}^{n} t_{k,n} \cdot a_k -a \right| \le $$

$$\le \left| \sum_{k=1}^{N_1 -1} t_{k,n} \cdot a_k \right| + \left| \sum_{k=N_1}^{n} t_{k,n} \cdot a_k  -a\right|.$$

The first term converges to zero by $(I)$. The second term is equal to:

$$\left| \sum_{k=N_1}^{n} t_{k,n} \cdot (a_k -a) + a\left( \sum_{k=N_1}^{n} t_{k,n} -1\right) \right| \le \left| \sum_{k=N_1}^{n} t_{k,n} \cdot (a_k -a) \right| + \left| a\left( \sum_{k=N_1}^{n} t_{k,n} -1 \right) \right| \le$$

$$\le  M \varepsilon + |a|\left|  \sum_{k=1}^{n} t_{k,n} -1  - \sum_{k=1}^{N_1 -1}t_{k,n} \right| \le M \varepsilon + |a|\left|  \sum_{k=1}^{n} t_{k,n} -1 \right| + |a| \left|\sum_{k=1}^{N_1 -1}t_{k,n} \right| .$$

The second inequality is due to $(III)$. The second term is less or equal to $|a| \varepsilon$ due to $(II)$. The last term converges to zero by $(I)$. Therefore the entire thing is less or equal than some multiple of $\varepsilon$.

Is this proof correct? I didn't write out the ending explicitly here (as in, pick $N_2$ such that (...) is satisfied, then for $n>N\equiv \max \{ N_1, N_2\}$ etc.), but is the idea ok?

Comment: Corrected, it was a typo.